# Do I need an SSL Certificate?

Tags: security, https, security-certificate

I'm thinking about building an app that lets users upload images to sites like Flickr. They would need to enter their password to do this. I would send the data through PHP, do I need to get a SSL certificate for that?

Comment: It could be done without, just like I could juggle knives. The answer is yes, you need SSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a certificate if you will use HTTPS encrypting the traffic. Since you are requiring a login I would say that it will be necessary (not technically but sending the information *in clear* is not a good option).